# View/Model/Controller : How to design hierarchical data variable

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtreeview

In PyQt4 Model-View [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcN94yMOkyU&index=10&list=PL8B63F2091D787896) the author
designs `Node()` Class to be used with `QAbstractItemModel` linked to `QTreeView`:

```
class Node(object):    
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):        
        self._name = name
        self._children=[]
        self._parent=parent

        if parent is not None:
            parent.addChild(self)

    def typeInfo(self):
        return "NODE"

    def addChild(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def row(self):
        if self._parent is not None:
            return self._parent._children.index(self)
```

Then he proceeds with declaring a data variable itself.
First he declares a `rootNode` variable to be used as a parent to all top level item-variables:

```
rootNode = Node("Root")
```

Then he declares two top level item-variables A and B: `childNodeA0` and `childNodeB0`.
And for each of these two top-level item-variables two child item-variables are declared
(I renamed the variables to make things look more generic):

```
childNodeA0 = Node("childNodeA0",  rootNode)
childNodeA1 = Node("childNodeA1",  childNodeA0)
childNodeA2 = Node("childNodeA2",  childNodeA1)

childNodeB0 = Node("childNodeB0",  rootNode)
childNodeB1 = Node("childNodeB1",  childNodeB0)
childNodeB3 = Node("childNodeB3",  childNodeB1)
```

Here is the schematic representation of data stored in rootNode variable:

```
|------Root
        |------childNodeA0
                |------childNodeA1
                        |------childNodeA2

        |------childNodeB0
                |------childNodeB1
                        |------childNodeB3
```

Now I declare a third item variable called `childNodeC0`:

```
childNodeC0 = Node("childNodeC0",  rootNode)
```

I pass `rootNode` as its parent. Here is the schematics:

```
|------Root
        |------childNodeA0
                |------childNodeA1
                        |------childNodeA2

        |------childNodeB0
                |------childNodeB1
                        |------childNodeB3

        |------childNodeC0
```

Now using `.addChild()` method I append `childNodeC0` variable as a child of `childNodeB0`.
So `childNodeC0` is a child of two variables: it is a child of `rootNode` and `childNodeB0`:

```
childNodeB0.addChild(childNodeC0)
```

Here is the schematics:

```
|------Root
        |------childNodeA0
                |------childNodeA1
                        |------childNodeA2   


        |------childNodeB0
                |------childNodeB1
                        |------childNodeB3    

                |------childNodeC0    

        |------childNodeC0
```

All goes as expected. But when this data variable is assigned to a "real" Model the `childNodeC0` item-variable only shows up as a child of `Root` and not as a child of `childNodeB0`. Aside from it the `childNodeB0` item-variable is shown in TreeView twice: as a child of Root (as it is supposed to be). And it is also shown as a child of itself!:

[image]

**Question:**

How to make TreeView to show a data stored in a root variable properly?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class Node(object):    
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):        
        self._name = name
        self._children=[]
        self._parent=parent

        if parent is not None:
            parent.addChild(self)

    def typeInfo(self):
        return "NODE"

    def addChild(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def row(self):
        if self._parent is not None:
            return self._parent._children.index(self)

    def log(self, tabLevel=-1):
        output     = ""
        tabLevel += 1

        for i in range(tabLevel):
            output += "\t"

        output += "|------" + self._name + "\n"

        for child in self._children:
            output += child.log(tabLevel)

        tabLevel -= 1
        output += "\n"

        return output

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.log()

class SceneGraphModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):    
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super(SceneGraphModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._rootNode = root

    def rowCount(self, parent):    

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentNode = self._rootNode
        else:
            parentNode = parent.internalPointer()
            # print 'VALID: ', type(parent), parent.row(), parent.column()

        return parentNode.childCount()

    def columnCount(self, parent):   
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):     
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        node = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return node.name()            

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole): 
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:                
                node = index.internalPointer()
                node.setName(value)                
                return True
        return False    

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):   
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return "Column #0"         

    def flags(self, index):         
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable    

    def parent(self, index):   

        node = self.getNode(index)
        parentNode = node.parent()

        if parentNode == self._rootNode:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentNode.row(), 0, parentNode)        

    def index(self, row, column, parent):   

        parentNode = self.getNode(parent)
        childItem = parentNode.child(row)

        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def getNode(self, index):    
        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            if node:
                return node            
        return self._rootNode    








if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    rootNode   = Node("Root")
    childNodeA0 = Node("childNodeA0",  rootNode)
    childNodeA1 = Node("childNodeA1",  childNodeA0)
    childNodeA2 = Node("childNodeA2",  childNodeA1)

    childNodeB0 = Node("childNodeB0",  rootNode)
    childNodeB1 = Node("childNodeB1",  childNodeB0)
    childNodeB3 = Node("childNodeB3",  childNodeB1)

    childNodeC0 = Node("childNodeC0",  rootNode)
    childNodeB0.addChild(childNodeC0)    

    treeView=QtGui.QTreeView()    

    model = SceneGraphModel(rootNode)
    treeView.setModel(model)
    treeView.show()

    print rootNode

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that with this data model you can't have a Node having 2 different parents.
The `addChild` is confusing because it seems that you can do it.
If you look in the scene graph model, it will ask the `Node` for it's parent (in `parent(self, index)`):

```
parentNode = node.parent()
```

and `Node.parent()` only returns the parent defined at the construction of the item:

```
return self._parent
```

If you want to have the same child at 2 different locations you may want to copy it or to improve the data model.